# How to show a random sentence in css

Tags: html, css

I have a few sentences that I want to use on a loading animation.

"Have you lost weight?",
"Just count to 10",
"Why so serious?",
"It's not you. It's me."

I have this css code to present the loading:

```
.loading .spinner:Before{content:"Discovering new ways of making you wait..."; position:absolute; bottom:50px; text-align:center; left:0; right:0; font-size:23px}
```

How can I make the sentences appear randomly?

Thank you sou much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `content` property to the `data-content` attribute of the element, then use JavaScript to randomly set a value from an array to that attribute.

```js
const possibleContent = ["Have you lost weight?", "Just count to 10", "Why so serious?", "It's not you. It's me."];

spinner.setAttribute('data-content', possibleContent[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleContent.length)]);
```

```css
.loading .spinner:Before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 23px
}
```

```html
<div class="loading"><div class="spinner" id="spinner"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :)